# Parsing text file to make a CSV file using sed

Tags: mysql, bash, csv, sed

I have a multi-gigabyte text file that looks like this:

```
>seq1
AAAUAAAUAAAUAAA
............... (  0.00)
>seq2
AAAUAAAUAAAUAAU
............... (  0.00)
>seq3
AAAUAAAUAAAUAAC
............... (  0.00)
>seq4
AAAUAAAUAAAUAAG
............... (  0.00)
>seq5
AAAUAAAUAAAUAUA
............... (  0.00)
```

And I need to get it into a format that I can dump into a MySQL table. My thought is to make it a CSV file that looks like:

```
>seq1,AAAUAAAUAAAUAAA,...............,(  0.00)
>seq2,AAAUAAAUAAAUAAU,...............,(  0.00)
```

But I'm not at all certain how to write the regex to make sed do its thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
sed '/^>seq[0-9]/{N;N;s/\n/,/g;s/ \((  [0-9]\.[0-9][0-9])\)/,\1/}' file
```

**Note :** : The `-i` option edit the file *in place*, with no confirmation.

- `/>seq[0-9]/` search for lines starting with `>seq` followed by one number
- `N;N;s/\n/,/g;`replace next two newline character with commas
- last substitute command replace decimal number between parenthesis with same string preceded with comma

Comment: Worked straight out of the gate! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

With a perl command line *(assuming dots are nucleotides)*:

```
perl -0076 -pe 's/\b\s+/,/g' file
```

`-0` changes the record separator to `>` (076 in octal)
`-p` prints automatically the record
`-e` executes the following commands